# Undefined variable ins_id in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

in the below code I am getting ins_id undefined when making AJAX call.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

        var state_id;
        var city_id;
        var ins_id;

        $('#state_id').change(function(){
            var state_id = $(this).val();   
            console.log(state_id); 
            if(state_id){
                $.ajax({
                   type:"GET",
                   url:"http://domain/?state_id="+state_id,
                   success:function(res){               
                    if(res){
                        console.log(res);
                        $("#city_id").empty();
                        $("#city_id").append('<option>Select</option>');
                        $.each(res,function(key,value){
                            $("#city_id").append('<option value="'+value.city_id+'">'+value.city_name+'</option>');
                        });           
                    }else{
                       $("#city_id").empty();
                    }
                   }
                });
            }else{
                $("#city_id").empty();
            }      
       });    


        $('#city_id').change(function(){
            var city_id     = $(this).val();
            var ins_id  = $("ins_id").val(); // I AM GETTING undefined ins_id 
            var t = "city_id="+city_id+"&ins_id="+ins_id;
            console.log(t);

            if(city_id){
                $.ajax({
                   type:"GET",
                   url:"http://domain/?city_id="+city_id+"&ins_id="+ins_id,
                   success:function(res){               
                    if(res){
                        console.log(res);
                        $("#is_office").append('<option>Select</option>');
                        $("#app_office").append('<option>Select</option>');
                        $.each(res,function(key,value){
                            $("#is_office").append('<option value="'+value.office_id+'">'+value.office_name+'</option>');
                            $("#app_office").append('<option value="'+value.office_id+'">'+value.office_name+'</option>');
                        });           
                    }else{
                       $("#is_office").empty();
                       $("#app_office").empty();
                    }
                   }
                });
            }else{
                $("#is_office").empty();
                $("#app_office").empty();
            }      
       });    
    });
</script>
```

I have spend more than two hours just to figure out what is wrong with this code, tried different browsers, but no avail. Kindly help.

Comment: should it be `$("#ins_id")` maybe?

Comment: Some HTML and/or CSS to go with that Javascript would help.

Comment: Thank you so much @KarlReid.

Comment: And thank you everyone for helping to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just check this line again

```
var ins_id  = $("ins_id").val();
```

If `ins_id` ia an element id then you need to write

```
var ins_id  = $("#ins_id").val();
```

If it is a class name then you need to specify

```
var ins_id  = $(".ins_id").val();
```

According to the name `ins_id` i think that it is self explanatory for the element id. Always use the proper jquery selector when getting and setting the values.

Answer (score 2):

```
var ins_id  = $("ins_id").val();
```

Above line should be replaced by

```
var ins_id  = $("#ins_id").val();
```